# Como agrupar un array multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php

estaría agradecido de su ayuda.

Tengo una variable `$_SESSION['articulos']` ,  la cual se ve de la siguiente manera

```
1: {id: '1', descripcion: 'Cama King (Incluye Colchon)', categoria: 'Camas', cantidad: '1', volumen: '2.6'}
2: {id: '2', descripcion: 'Cama 2 Plazas (Incluye Colchon)', categoria: 'Camas', cantidad: 5, volumen: '2.0'}
5: {id: '5', descripcion: 'Cama Nido 1 Plaza (Incluye Colchon)', categoria: 'Camas', cantidad: '1', volumen: '1.0'}
9: {id: '9', descripcion: 'Cuna No Desarmable', categoria: 'Camas', cantidad: 2, volumen: '2.0'}
12: {id: '12', descripcion: 'Cama Baul 1 Plaza', categoria: 'Camas', cantidad: '1', volumen: '2.04'}
13: {id: '13', descripcion: 'Cama Baul 2 Plazas', categoria: 'Camas', cantidad: '1', volumen: '3.5'}
54: {id: '54', descripcion: 'Silla Reclinable', categoria: 'Sillas', cantidad: '1', volumen: '0.4'}
60: {id: '60', descripcion: 'Piso Alto ', categoria: 'Sillas', cantidad: '1', volumen: '0.2'}
108: {id: '108', descripcion: 'Comedor 8 O 10 Personas', categoria: 'Terraza', cantidad: '1'
```

Estoy mostrando los datos en pantalla de la siguiente forma, pero me gustaría poder mostrarlos agrupados por categoría, ya que actualmente se muestran como una lista única.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['articulos'])){
   $HTML .= '  <div>
                  <h3>Listado Articulos</h3>';
   foreach($_SESSION['articulos'] as $articulo){
     $categoria = $articulo['categoria'];
     $cantidad = $articulo['cantidad'];
     $descripcion = $articulo['descripcion'];
     $HTML .= '   <p>'.$descripcion.' <span>('.$cantidad.')</span></p>';
   }
   $HTML .= '  </div>';
}
```

Comment: simplemente puedes hacer una condicional donde ```if($_SESSION['categoria'] == 'N Categoria'){ echo $_SESSION['descripcion'] etc..}``` pero si se trata de N categorias esto no te va a funcionar ya tendrias que utilizar otro metodo

Comment: El otro metodo es que inicialices un array fuero del foreach, y dentro del foreach haces un push cada ves que una categoria no se encuentre en dicho array, si no se encuentra crea una lista con esos productos, si se encuentra la categoria simplemente añadelo a esa sección, alli si no te tengo el codigo